# How to get the unsample data from UA Query Explorer?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I tried to query the unsample data from UA
but no matter how i tried ( i tried to query only single day, and only query for a single event label, the result data still showed with sampling)
i also set the sampling level, but its doesn't work.
it should list down 30k+ rows for one day.
what should i do? thanks a lot!!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sampling size results when the amount of data is to great so the data will be sampled

The options you have are to reduces the number of days you are requesting data for as well as reducing the amount of data.   The best way to do that is to limit the number of dimensions and metrics

[image]

There is no option to completely remove sampling.

Comment: Thank you~ also have another question, will the same problem happened, if i export data by Rgoogleanalytics via google api?

Comment: Rgoogleanalytics  uses the google analytics api as far as i know.   The results will be the same.